# Pushing array generated inside a function to a global variable

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me understand why I can't push an array to the generatedNumbers global variable with this function:

```
var totalFrames = document.getElementById("totalFrames").value;
var framesToSkip = document.getElementById("framesToSkip").value;
var generatedNumbers = [];

function clickGenerate() {
  for (var i = 1; i <= totalFrames; i++) {
    if ((i % framesToSkip) === 0) {
      // do nothing
    } else {
      generatedNumbers.push(i);
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("numberList").innerHTML = generatedNumbers;
}
```

You can see it accompanied by the html here:

https://jsfiddle.net/bdorrance/wszzvpu1/

If I put the variables inside the function, it works fine, but I need the variables to be global so they can be accessed by other functions. You can see that code here:

https://jsfiddle.net/bdorrance/t246rnxe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is not that global array.
Your problem is that you dont gather the actual valus of "totalFrames" and "totalFramesSkip".
As the function is invoked. The values of the variables `totalFrames` and `framesToSkip` are `0`

You have to gather the actual values on function invocation.
Add these lines IN your function:

```
framesToSkip = document.getElementById("framesToSkip").value;
totalFrames = document.getElementById("totalFrames").value;
```

Then it should work

Comment: Hey @Livingstone thank you very much for your insight. That did solve my issue. However, I am not 100% sure why these variables had to be placed inside the function and that the function couldn't read the variables if they were global. I am fairly new to JavaScript and programming in general. Can you explain to me exactly whats happening here. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @bdorrance - my answer explains why. You're defining those variables before there is anything placed into those inputs. You need to grab those values only once the button has been clicked. So you can define them in a global sense outside of the function initially w/o a value, then update them within your function once the button has been clicked.

Comment: @bdorrance - In your code you just gather the values of the textfied once the site is loaded. That means you'll get the default value. These are stored in your two variables. So, when the function `clickGenerate` is called it will work with these "unmodified" values. You have to get sure you get the actual values. For that you have to gather the value every single time you call your function. Hope that helps. And sorry for my bad english;)

Comment: @Livingstone this comment cleared it up perfectly for me. That makes total sense now. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You're defining your `totalFrames` and `framesToSkip` variables **before** you enter anything into those input boxes or clicking the button to generate. There is nothing in the boxes, so there is nothing to grab, and nothing to push to the array.

In your jsfiddle with the variables included, the variables are not defined until the button is clicked, at which point you have numbers already entered in the box.

You can make the variables global by defining them initially outside of the function, e.g. `var totalFrames, framesToSkip;`, then assigning to them the values of the input boxes within your onClick function.

Revised JS:

```
var totalFrames, framesToSkip;

function clickGenerate() {
    totalFrames = document.getElementById("totalFrames").value;
    framesToSkip = document.getElementById("framesToSkip").value;
    var generatedNumbers = [];

    for (var i = 1; i <= totalFrames; i++) {
        if ((i % framesToSkip) === 0) {
            // do nothing
        } else {
            generatedNumbers.push(i);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("numberList").innerHTML = generatedNumbers;
}

function showFullResult() {
    document.getElementById("numberList").innerHTML = "full test";
}

function showShortResult() {
    document.getElementById("numberList").innerHTML = "short test";
}
```

[Here is an updated example in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t246rnxe/2/)

Answer (score -1):

As others have said: move the variables for totalFrames and framesToSkip inside your function:

```
var totalFrames;
var framesToSkip;
function clickGenerate() {
    totalFrames = document.getElementById("totalFrames").value;
    framesToSkip = document.getElementById("framesToSkip").value;
    console.log(totalFrames)
    for (var i = 1; i <= totalFrames; i++) {
        if ((i % framesToSkip) === 0) {
            // do nothing
        } else {
            generatedNumbers.push(i);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("numberList").innerHTML = generatedNumbers;
}
```

Comment: OP wants the `totalFrames` and `framesToSkip` variables to be global rather than defined within that function. OP already provided this example in their post.

Comment: Thank you TimMcClure and @Veo.